# Help for simple regression

Tags: regression

my research question is:
"Can we say that the number of hours of Internet use increases with Internet purchase?"
with the variables:
- Use of Internet per week (Use in hours)
- If respondent has already made a purchase on the Internet (1 = yes, 2 = no)

Therefore, this statement told me that my dependant variable is number of hours of Internet use and my independant variable is Online purchase.
But that seems me a little weird. How can I check if I don't have to reverse my IV and my DV ? 
(I use SPSS)
Thank you

Comment: Independent and dependent variables are determined **a priori** based on the research question, so your question about "checking if [you] don't have to reverse your IV and DV" does not make sense (check for what?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to prove that the number of hours spent on the internet is different for users who have previously made an on-line purchase simply by running a t-test. Equivalently, an ANOVA or an OLS regression with dummy variables (`1 = purchase`; `0 = no purchase`) will provide you with the same results.

How well the assumptions will be met may be a different topic.

Comment: 5k man! Congratulations!